# git smart http no authentication on info/refs?service=XXX, has authentication on git-upload-pack and git-receive-pack

Tags: git, apache

If nothing to be pushed / pulled, I do not want password to be supplied.
And allow git ls-remote to run without password

```
*.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
*.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
```

I only need authentication on

```
*.git/git-upload-pack
*.git/git-receive-pack
```

/etc/apache/httpd.conf

```
<LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-(upload|receive)-pack$">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "staff only"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache/apache.pwd
    Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

However this does not work. It does not ask for password at all.

I use Ubuntu 10.04, Apache 2.2.14, Git 1.7.11.3.

Directory structure: any depth (more than 1 subdir) of path from /git to .git folders

Comment: Is it a bug in apache or git?